# jQuery-validate not working with Kendo Button (jsfiddle included)

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, jquery-validate

Took me a while to realize that the reason why jquery-validate wasn't working in my Kendo Mobile application was because my submit button was a Kendo Button.

Here is a jsfiddle to demonstrate:

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/newblt123/YSDGL/4/)

```
<div id="phoneApp" style="display:none;">
    <div id="forms" data-role="view">
        <form>
                <ul data-role="listview" data-style="inset">
                    <li>
                        Amount
                        <input type="number" step="0.01" name="amount-fr" />
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Description
                        <textarea name="description-fr" ></textarea>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>        
            <button type="submit" data-role="button">Submit (Data-role = button)</button>    
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

$(function() {
    var app;

    app = new kendo.mobile.Application($("#phoneApp"), {
        layout: "phoneDefault",
        transition: 'slide'
    });

    //Adjust visibility of proper app container
    $("#phoneApp").show();

    $( "form" ).validate({
        rules: {
            "amount-fr": {
                required: true,
                min: 1
            },
            "description-fr": {
                required: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            "amount-fr": {
                required: "amount required !",
                min: "min is 1 !"
            },
            "description-fr": {
                required: "description required !"
            }
        }
    });
});
```

That being said, is there any workaround to make jquery-validate work ? I kind of would like to keep my buttons as Kendo buttons as they provide functionalities and styles.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that although you've set the button to a `type="submit"`, you've set the `data-role` to `button` which effectively does the same as a `type="button"`.  In other words, the `data-role="button"` is making your `type="submit"` behave like a `type="button"`.

The only workaround is that you must manually capture the `button` and force a `submit`.

```
$('button').on('click', function(e) {  // capture the button click
    e.preventDefault();  // the default button functionality is always ignored
    $('form').submit();  // force a submit
});
```

Although I think you should add an `id` to your `<button>` and `<form>` so that you can target them more precisely.

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/YSDGL/5/**

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Jquery Validator, try using Kendo Validator.

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/validator/index

Comment: That's not what he asked.